# Create macro to output and update file after merging several excel files

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice at VBA. I am using Excel 2013 for this task. I have several Excel files I am combining into a single file with multiple sheets using the macro below.

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyPath = "H:\Survey Research\ECAS\Reports\2015\Tracks"
    Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

        wbSrc.Close False

    strFilename = Dir()

Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I want each sheet in the new file to take the name of its original file. I tried to edit the code below and include in the macro above, but while I didn't get an error message, it did not accomplish the task.

```
Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks("import-   sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
```

Once the files have been merged and the sheets named, I want to output the new file and to easily update it if the data in my original files change. 
Is it possible to achieve all of this with one macro? If so, could anyone  suggest a way to write a Macro in Excel to automatically name the sheets, output the file and update it if changes are made to the data in the original files?

Comment: What *exactly* (provide details!) is preventing you from doing what you want to do?  If you have existing code which has problems, update your question to include it.  If you don't have any code, try writing some and then post back with that code and a description of what error messages etc you might be getting.

Comment: Missing the "**?**" No questions and no requests... just *I have...* and *I would like to [do]...* so um... no one holds you back. Just do it. If you have some specific questions, just come back and ask.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear with my question. I edited the question. Thank you for the suggestions. @Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part I think you only need to add one line:

```
Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
        'name the tab according to the file name
        wsSrc.Name = Replace(strFilename,".xls","")

        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

        wbSrc.Close False

    strFilename = Dir()

Loop
```

The last part about updating the workbook if the source files change is potentially much more complex: the easiest approach would be to re-run the consolidation code.  If that doesn't work for you then you'd need to add more details on that.